# If $f$ is a function from $X$ to $Y$ then does the equality $f[X]\setminus f[X\setminus U]=f[U]$ holds for any $U\in\mathcal P(X)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples

Given a function $f$ from $X$ to $Y$ I am try to prove or to disprove the equality
$$
\tag{1}\label{1}f[X]\setminus f[X\setminus U]=f[U]
$$
where $U\in\mathcal P(X)$. So I surely know thath for any $U,V\in\mathcal P(X)$ the euquality
$$
f[U]\setminus f[V]\subseteq f[U\setminus V]
$$
holds so that clearly the inclusion
$$
f[X]\setminus f[X\setminus U]\subseteq f\big[X\setminus(X\setminus U)\big]=f[U]
$$
holds. Now I am not to able to prove because if $f$ is not injective it is possibile that $f[U]$ and $f[X\setminus U]$ are not disjoint so that I suspect that $\eqref{1}$ does not holds but unfortunately I was not able to find a counterexample so that I thought to put a specific question where I ask to prove or disprove the equality. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: Consider constant map ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=x^2$. Take $U=\mathbb{R}_+^*$.

Then $f(\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R}_+$ and $f(\mathbb{R}\setminus U)=f(\mathbb{R}_-)=\mathbb{R}_+$, so $$f(\mathbb{R}) \setminus f(\mathbb{R}\setminus U) = \emptyset \neq f(U) = \mathbb{R}_+^*$$

Comment: Is $\Bbb R^*_+$ just the set of positive numbers?

Comment: I use the notations $\mathbb{R}_+^* = \lbrace x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x > 0 \rbrace$ and $\mathbb{R}_+ = \lbrace x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x \geq 0 \rbrace$.

Comment: Okay, nice counterexample! I upvoted the question: when the site lets to approve I will surely do it. Thanks very much for your assistance! ;-)

Comment: Tip: $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and $\mathbb{R}_{≥0}$ are more universally understood